# How do I conditionally clear content in a row contained in a range based on a checkbox?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a sheet that I need to be able to clear a row of data at a time without breaking the formatting.

**What I want it to do:**
If checkbox in column "J" is checked and they click the reset button, it clears all rows with checked "J" and then sorts the remaining data by column 'C'.

**What I have done:**
I have cobbled together most of it, but when I run it, it clears the whole range rather than just the rows with the checked box.

This is the script I have so far, and I feel I'm close but can't see where my error is:

```
      function ResetCompletedOnly() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('WITH RESET');
      var r = sheet.getRange('B15:P51');
      var v = r.getValues();
      for(var i=v.length-1;i=1;i--)
        if(v[9,i]=1){
          r.clearContent(i+1)}
      else if(v[9,i]=0){
        r.sort(3)
      }
      };
```

***9/24/19 ADDED THE 
[EXAMPLE SHEET HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRefZqsu7NeuXkgR2kNfdHfcCtNipZLO0o9xqhBQLjo/edit?usp=sharing)(link)***

**Ideally what I'm trying to do and why:**

[BEFORE HITTING RESET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN163.png)(img) the sheet is a jumble of completed sales which have been installed or otherwise activated but the sales person hasn't been paid out for, orders that have a delayed install date, or are delayed due to a dispute which has to be resolved via inquiry. Ideally once the sale has been paid out, there is no further action required by the sales rep, so it's ok to clear this data.

CLEARING rather than DELETING is crucial due to the formatting and the constant daily reuse/refresh of the sales tracker.

The folks I'm making this tracker for are very computer challenged (Copy Paste is a difficult concept for them) and so it needs to be simple, easy, and clean for them to use continuously.

[AFTER HITTING RESET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plHsQ.png)(img) only the rows which were paid out and required no further action from the sales person have been cleared. Afterwards, the remaining rows were then sorted according the date they were first entered into the sheet so that the oldest and most pressing is always at the top.

Sorry for the delay in the update, it's been a crazy week and I wanted to make sure I tinkered with all the suggestions first before posting the update. I'm still digging into the tutorials and information given but am struggling a little to fully grasp the scripting language and what I'm trying to ask the script to do.

THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR YOUR SUGGESTIONS SO FAR!

Comment: You're accessing the data wrong; `v[9,i]` doesn't make sense, to access 2D arrays the syntax would be  `v[9][i]`, change that and check if it's fixed. you're also clearing the entire range when you call `r.clearContent(i+1)` regardless of anything, what you need to do is clear the "rows" in `v` and then use `r.setValues(v)` to set the new values. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) on working with Spreadsheets in Apps Script.

Comment: @AMolina may I suggest moving your response into an answer? I feel like you provided a solution just now.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the v[9][i] but it still cleared the whole sheet so I'm still doing something wrong. I'll definitely check out the tutorial you suggested! 

I've done a lot of searching on forums trying to find similar functions but have been having trouble. I appreciate the point in the right direction! I'll try to figure out how to incorporate the r.setValues that you're suggesting!

Comment: @Joy When you call `r.clearContent(i+1)` it's gonna clear the entire range. There is also a problem with `sort()`, as you can see in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)), it sorts by column by default, and the changes you are making are of the columns, meaning, your sort won't organize the columns, but the rows, so you will be left with blank columns. Please share a sanitized copy of your sheet, but you might have to reconsider how your data is arranged. Also, Thank you @yaakovBressler, but I think there is more needed for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

When you use `range.getValues()` you get a two dimensional array [][] or an array of arrays.  In this case `vA[0][0]` is the value in `B15` and `vA[1][0]` is the value in `B16`.  So the first index is for the rows and the second is for the columns although the arrays start with zero and row and columns start with one.

There is not a `range.clearContents(p)` function so I assumed you wanted to delete that row.  `vA[0]` is actually row 15 so that's why the 15 in `sh.deleteRow(i+15-d++);` and the d just keeps track of how many rows have been deleted.  I didn't see much sense in sorting during the for loop because that would potentially mess all the rows up so I waited until after the for loop was completed.  This may not be what your after...we can discuss that further.

```
function ResetCompletedOnly() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('WITH RESET');
  var rg=sh.getRange('B15:P51');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][8]==1){//column J
      sh.deleteRow(i+15-d++);
    }
  }
  rg.sort({column:3,ascending:true});//column C
}
```

**References**

[Sheet.clearContents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearContents())

[Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

[Sheet.deleteRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRow(Integer))

[Range.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

> This is probably not the exact answer that your looking for but hopefully it will help you to learn a little more about Google Apps Script in order to get the results that you need.

You did an excellent job in creating your question although a bit more research in to the Google Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/) would have been helpful.

I can't really test this without your example spreadsheet but I think this will clear all of the row cells that don't have formulas.  It will run much slower because I'm clearing them one cell at a time so that I can avoid messing with the formulas.  I tested it a little with random numbers and it works.

```
function ResetCompletedOnly() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('WITH RESET');
  var rg=sh.getRange('B15:P51');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vF=rg.getFormulas();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][8]==1){//column J
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
        if(!vF[i][j]) {
          sh.getRange(i+15,j+2).setValue('');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  rg.sort({column:3,ascending:true});//column C the column number is not relative to the range.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Deleting rows causes an issue because I need the sheet to be constantly reusable for people with limited computer skills. The sheet has many lays of conditional formatting, drop menus, and check boxes to make inputing the data as easy as possible.

Thank you for the links, I honestly  understand only about 3/4 of what he functions do.

Embedded questions: [9] was trying to reference column J. Column J are the checkboxes that will be the deciding factor if the data should be cleared out, or if it should be recompiled and sorted by date (column C).

Comment: So I gather you would prefer clearing the rows.  I'd find that a lot easier to do with an  example spreadsheet.  I'd guess that you want to leave formulas and  only clear values and strings.

Comment: So after a LONG time working with it and fiddling, I realized I had the button calling the wrong function. This worked!! Thank you so much!!