# Assistance with Converting a Script from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, button, range, reset

I received assistance with scripting a rest button for a complex sales tracker about 2 years ago and the original solution was extremely helpful. ([Original Question for Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952071/how-do-i-conditionally-clear-content-in-a-row-contained-in-a-range-based-on-a-ch))

I've been able to modify that script for multiple projects since. However, I'm very stuck for this particular project. Any help converting the script would be most appreciated!

I've been puzzling over this for over a month now, trying different things and thus far nothing has worked. I know that it's probably something simple. So, I would especially like the know the what's and why's of the conversion, if you don't mind sharing that information as part of your answer so that I may learn for the future, I would greatly appreciate it!

**The situation:** I have created a dashboard of To Do lists to help keep me organized in my new position. There are 4 To Do lists, and a summary box on the same sheet (see example sheet below). I'm trying to code the Reset Button for my Personal To Do list. This list is from range I4:K26, and needs to be reusable in that range. The rest button is intended to clear contents for completed tasks, without deleting rows or formatting, and sort the list by due date and name.

**How it's going:** I have been able to convert portions of the original coding. The Reset button sorts the items how I would like it to, but it does not clear contents.

**Here is the [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ftF9KyeWuIGDBcYEUComIY_2pLfNk9iDxHeG0l-FvQw/edit?usp=sharing) of the current project.**

**This is the original script:**

```
//The one that worked!

function ResetCompletedOnly() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SALES: RESET 2020');
  var rg=sh.getRange('B19:T104');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vF=rg.getFormulas();
 for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][9]==1){//column K
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
        if(!vF[i][j]) {
          sh.getRange(i+19,j+2).setValue('');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  rg.sort({column:3,ascending:true});//column C the column number is not relative to the range.
}
```

**This is my attempt thus far at converting it:**

```
//Testing something new..

function ResetClearContents() {
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp
               .getActive()
               .getSheetByName("ResetToDo");
 var rg=sh.getRange('I4:K26');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vF=rg.getFormulas();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][3]==1){//column K based on range I4:K26
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
        if(!vF[i][j]) {
          sh.getRange(i+4,j+9).clearContent();
                  }
      }
    }
  }
  rg.sort([{column:11,ascending:true},{column:9,ascending:true},{column:10,ascending:true}]);//column I the column number is not relative to the range.
}
```

This is what it looks like before running the script:

[image]

This is what it SHOULD look like when the script is done:

[image]

However, this is what the script is currently doing:

[image]

**Thank you for taking the time to review my dilemma. I appreciate you having a look!
**
(**Side question:** Google just updated its data validation drop down menus to have a constant background color when there is data (seen on the example sheet in range K30:K41). I hate this feature. Is there any way to make the data validation box transparent to allow the alternating colors to show??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the range I4:K26, column K is item #2 in the array, as arrays start from 0.

Instead of

```
 if(vA[i][3]==1)
```

Write

```
 if(vA[i][2]==1)
```